# Ruby on rails tables Polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relation

I'm trying to generate an Order for a User that contains series, seasons and chapters. These are my Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :lines
   has_many :products, through: :lines
end

class Line < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product (THIS CAN BE A SERIE,SEASON,CHAPTER)
end
```

How I can do this relationship? What I have to put on Serie,Season,Chapter tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

First, update `lines` table:

```
class AddProductsToLines < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    edit_table :lines do |t|
      # ... other attributes
      t.references :product, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Second, update your models:

```
class Line < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true 
end

class Serie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines, as: :product
end

class Season < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines, as: :product
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines, as: :product
end
```